# Minimize button missing when using Microsoft.Windows.Shell

Tags: wpf, windows-shell

I am using `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` in order to get rounded form:

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"

<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <shell:WindowChrome
        ResizeBorderThickness="0"
        CaptionHeight="0"
        CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"
        GlassFrameThickness="0">
    </shell:WindowChrome>
</shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

And although i define this 2:

```
ShowCloseButton="True"
ShowMinButton="True"
```

I only can see the `Close` button.

`Mininize` button is missing

Comment: This assembly is not being maintained, I'd assume they gave up on it when Win10 was released.  Its visual style can no longer be tinkered with.  Remarkable that you see a Close button at all, given that you set the caption height to 0.  I suspect you see the Win10 chrome.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, any suggestions what to do ?

Comment: Just the obvious ones, delete that assembly from your disk so it can do no further harm.  And google "wpf custom window chrome", lotsa hits.

Comment: Why it could do harm ?

Comment: When setting the GlassFrameThickness property to 0, you are supposed to create custom buttons yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190041/show-default-window-buttons-on-wpf-window-using-windowchrome